# How to prevent Laptop/ Computer screen from locking using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code in an Excel Visual Basic module which prevents the laptop / computer screen from locking.

The mouse events I call in the module are quite intrusive.

```
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTFaha_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Are there less intrusive events which will prevent the screen from locking?

This is being used in a wider automation therefore the solution has to be VBA.

Full code:

```vb
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As 
 Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
 Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
 Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
 Dim TimerActive As Boolean

Sub KeepWindowsActive()
TimerActive = True
'move cursor and click
SetCursorPos 200, 200 'x and y position
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTFaha_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:03:00"), "KeepWindowsActive"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetThreadExecutionState Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal esFlags As Long) As Long

Const ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED As Long = &H1
Const ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED As Long = &H2
Const ES_CONTINUOUS As Long = &H80000000

' Enable away mode and prevent the sleep idle time-out. Called periodically this is needed (every 59 sec, change to longer interval if you want)
' I've this sub called in Workbook_Open
Public Sub PreventLocking()
    SetThreadExecutionState ES_CONTINUOUS Or ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED Or ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:59"), Procedure:="PreventLocking"
End Sub

' Clear flags to disable away mode and allow the system to idle to sleep normally.
' I've this sub called in Workbook_BeforeClose, but it would probably be fine even w/o it
Public Sub ClearLockingFlags()
    SetThreadExecutionState ES_CONTINUOUS
End Sub
```